# How to restrict only a certain website from accessing my API gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, datadog

I am currently attempting to fetch monitor metrics from https://app.datadoghq.com, which will use a webhook to send data to the api gateway url I have created. The http api gateway will then trigger a lambda function, and store the received data in an S3.

I am now considering the security aspect of it. In particular, I want to restrict access to this api gateway, so that only https://app.datadoghq.com can access it, and so that api gateway can only accept headers from datadog. My question is, how can I go about doing this? I have looked into the CORS for http api gateways, but nothing seems to be working. Do I need to configure something else, like resource policies?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Options for restricting access to API Gateway described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-control-access-to-api.html).

Comment: @jarmod I wanted to ask, is this situation CORS related? As I'm researching it increasingly seems like I am doing something wrong by touching CORS.

Comment: I don't see how CORS would be an issue. The API requests from DataDog presumably are coming from their backend servers, not from a browser. I'd expect DataDog to be able to explain what authentication mechanisms they support when making these requests.

Comment: You could add a WAF ruleset to the API Gateway only allowing requests from that domain or range of IPs.